# Issue with Specific Cell Popover inside slds datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, aura

My use case is to implement specific dataTable cell popOver on click. Below is the code. Using lightning:overlayLibrary base component to show popOver. It is showing popOver but only on the first row of the table body.

**customTable.cmp**

```
   <aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
   <aura:attribute name="spinner" type="boolean" default="false"></aura:attribute>
   <aura:attribute name="cardTitle" type="string" default=""></aura:attribute>
   <aura:attribute name="data" type="object" ></aura:attribute>
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"></lightning:overlayLibrary>
   <lightning:card iconName="utility:fulfillment_order">
      <aura:set attribute="title">
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.cardTitle}">
            <lightning:formattedRichText value="{!v.cardTitle}"/>
         </aura:if>
      </aura:set>
      <aura:set attribute="body">
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.spinner}">
            <lightning:spinner variant="brand" title="Loading....." alternativeText="Loading....."
               size="small">
            </lightning:spinner>
         </aura:if>
         <aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.data))}">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-no-row-hover">
               <thead>
                  <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                     <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Test1">createdDate</div>
                     </th>
                     <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Test2">Name</div>
                     </th>
                     <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Test3">productName</div>
                     </th>
                     <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Test4">status</div>
                     </th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <aura:iteration items="{!v.data}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                     <aura:if isTrue="{!item}">
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <aura:if isTrue="{!item.createdDate}">
                                 <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!item.createdDate}" year="numeric"
                                    month="2-digit" day="2-digit">
                                 </lightning:formattedDateTime>
                              </aura:if>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <div class="mypopover" onclick="{!c.handleShowPopover1}" data-selected-Index="{!index}">
                                 {!item.Name}
                              </div>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <div class="slds-truncate">
                                 {!item.productName}
                              </div>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <div class="slds-truncate">
                                 {!item.status}
                              </div>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </aura:if>
                  </aura:iteration>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </aura:if>
      </aura:set>
   </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**customTableController.js**

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.doInitHelper(component);
  },

  handleShowPopover1: function(component,event) {
    try {
      var target = event.target;
      var dataEle = target.getAttribute("data-selected-Index");
      $A.createComponent(
        "c:popOver",
        {
          rowIndex: dataEle
        },
        function(content, status) {
          console.log("status ~~~~~~~~>  " + status);
          if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            component
              .find("overlayLib")
              .showCustomPopover({
                body: content,
                referenceSelector: ".mypopover",
                cssClass: "slds-popover_walkthrough"
              })
              .then(function(overlay) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  //close the popover after 3 seconds
                  overlay.close();
                }, 3000);
              });
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (Err) {
      console.log("Error ~~~~~> " + Err);
    }
  }
});
```

**customTableHelper.js**

```
({
  doInitHelper: function(component) {
    // turn on spinner
    var result = '[{"Id":"0","Name":"name1","createdDate":"2019-08-29T07:24:06.000Z","productName":"productName1"},{"Id":"1","Name":"name2","createdDate":"2019-08-29T12:29:03.000Z","productName":"productName2"},{"Id":"2","Name":"name3","createdDate":"2019-08-29T07:24:06.000Z","productName":"productName3"},{"Id":"3","Name":"name4","createdDate":"2019-08-29T12:29:03.000Z","productName":"productName4"},{"Id":"4","Name":"name5","createdDate":"2019-08-29T07:24:06.000Z","productName":"productName5"},{"Id":"5","Name":"name6","createdDate":"2019-08-29T12:29:03.000Z","productName":"productName6"}]';
    component.set("v.spinner", true);
    component.set(
      "v.data",
      JSON.parse(result)
    );
    this.setCardTitle(component, JSON.parse(result));
    // turn off spinner
    component.set("v.spinner", false);
  },

  setCardTitle: function(component, result) {
    component.set(
      "v.cardTitle",
      "<b>dummyCardTitle (" +
        ($A.util.isEmpty(result) ? 0 : result.length) +
        ")</b>"
    );
  }
});
```

**popOver.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="rowIndex" type="string" default=""/>
   <!--Declare Attribute-->
   <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
   <!--Component Start--> 
    <div class="slds-popover__body">
      <div class="slds-media">
         <div class="slds-media__body">
             <p>rowIndex:{!v.rowIndex}</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--Component End-->
</aura:component>
```

**Popover on the row 1**
[image]

**Popover on the row 2**
[image]

**Popover on the row 3**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading it in `aura:iteration` and you are not using [overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden), you implement the [slds-popover](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/popovers/) directly:

COMPONENT:

```
<td>
    <div class="mypopover slds-is-relative" data-selected-Index="{!index}">
        {!item.Name}
        <section class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left"
                 role="dialog">
            <div class="slds-popover__body" id="dialog-body-id-77">
                <p><c:POC_PopOver rowIndex="{!index}" /></p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.THIS .slds-popover {
    display:none;
}

.THIS .mypopover:hover .slds-popover {
    top: -0.7rem;
    left: 9rem;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: normal;
    display: block;
}
```